# how to get the uploaded image value using jquery i am using "var image_title = $("#image_title").val();"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using `var image_title = $("#image_title").val();` this to get the uploaded image value. But it is not working any other way to get uploaded image value?. The path should not come but it should be like "imagename.jpg".

Comment: So you want the filename ? Just go for something like $("img").attr("src") and cut off the rest of the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
var imagePath= $("#image_title").attr('src');

var imageNameIndex = imagePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var imageName = imagePath.substr(imageNameIndex);  //This will give you the image name
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i used like this it is working.                are_pic = $('#ar_pic').val();
imageNameIndex = are_pic.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
imageName = are_pic.substr(imageNameIndex);

Comment: The logics are same @user3750938 . If my answer is suitable for your question , Kindly vote up so that others knows too the solution of it .

Comment: '/' or '\\' depends what path you are getting for the image . I wrote it in general .

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically updating the DOM, use jquery .on() method. For exemple:

```
$("div").on("change","#image_title",function(){ ... });
```